# Cannot re-enable Submit button in Javascript after it has been clicked. ".querySelector().disabled = false" does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit, onsubmit

I am trying to create a simple google search bar in my website.  It works fine.  However, I am accounting for user error, and for some reason I cannot re-enable my submit button once it is clicked, under the condition that no input is provided.  Please see Javascript code below.

```js
const text = document.querySelector("#search");
const msg = document.querySelector(".msg");

document.querySelector(".google-form").addEventListener('submit', onclick)

function onclick(e) {
  if (text.value === '' || text.value === null) {
    e.preventDefault();
    msg.classList.add('error');
    msg.innerHTML = 'Please enter a proper search query';
    setTimeout(() => msg.remove(), 3000);
    document.querySelector("#button").disabled = false; // <-- This method doesn't seem to work.
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="google-form">
  <div class="msg"></div>
  <form id="my-form" action="https://www.google.com/search">
    <input id="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter Search">
    <button id="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

As you can see, if no text is input, it will let the user know they will need to enter an actual search query.  However, after that point, the submit button just wont work again.

I tried using .querySelector().disabled = false; , as well as .removeAttribute("disabled"), but nothing is working.  What exactly am I missing here, to re-activate the submit button once it was clicked with no input?

Comment: Why are you adding a `submit` event handler on a `<div>`? Also, where are you disabling the submit button?

Comment: Ah, I think you want `msg.innerHTML = ""` instead of `msg.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Your button works just fine. You just remove the complete element and then the `msg = document.querySelector(".msg");` doesn't find anything. In addition i would leave the timeout out and let the message there until the user writes something.

You should do it like that:

```js
const text = document.querySelector("#search");
const msg = document.querySelector(".msg");

document.querySelector(".google-form").addEventListener('submit', onclick)

function onclick(e) {
  msg.innerHTML= '';
  if (text.value === '' || text.value === null) {
    e.preventDefault();
    msg.classList.add('error');
    msg.innerHTML = 'Please enter a proper search query';
    document.querySelector("#button").disabled = false; // <-- This method doesn't seem to work.
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="google-form">
  <div class="msg"></div>
  <form id="my-form" action="https://www.google.com/search">
    <input id="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter Search">
    <button id="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When button `type` is set on `submit` value, it will send the information to the server anyway. (not if you use `preventDefault()` method!)

My suggestion is to change button `type` to `button` and then write an onclick event for it and check the validation there , if everything was right then call for form submit event!

This is how you can prevent incorrect information from being sent into the server side and avoid the errors that it can cause.